# django get previous url

Tags: django, url

i am using `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')` to get the previous url  , it works fine  when  the  url is inside my website but when  the url is outside  my website  (facebook)  it returns none  and the  template tag for **HTTP_REFERER** return the current url with  a facebook parameter :
http://127.0.0.1:8000/order_analytics/?fbclid=IwAR2nLUSZAAmJOdjS7UPw_jol14ZpOEW7QjxrUqrisFk1msWa_L9nZPWqyDg
what i want to get is **https://www.facebook.com/**

Comment: Certain browsers do not allow this for cross-origin https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/07/referrer-policy-new-chrome-default for privacy concerns.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ok then i think  i have to  search for the word fbclid inside the  the url  so i know it's from facebook ,how can i do that with django ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the `fbclid` with `request.GET`, and if it is present, you can detect the origin:

```
fbclid = request.GET.get('fbclid')
if fbclid is not None:
    # fbclid is the id of the facebook post
```